# Populando selects de cidades e estados com AJAX (PHP e jQuery Mobile)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Estou montando um *webapp* com o framework JQuery Mobile, PHP e AJAX.

Nesse app eu tenho um formulário com *selects* de `ESTADO` e `CIDADE`, foi feito um AJAX que quando seleciona o `ESTADO`, carrega as `CIDADES` de acordo com ESTADO.

O problema que estou tendo, e que o AJAX só carrega a primeira vez, e depois não mais após selecionar o `ESTADO` pela segunda vez ou mais vezes.

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#estados').change(function(){
                alert ('carrega cidade');
                $('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado='+$('#estados').val() );

            });
        });

    </script>
```

```php
<select name="estados" id="estados">
    <option value="0">ESTADO</option>
    <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_selectdb('proxima-corrida');

       $result = mysql_query("select * from proxc_estado");

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
            echo "<option value='".$row['id_estado']."'>".$row['estado']."</option>";

       }

    ?>
</select>


<select name="cidades" id="cidades">
    <option value="0">Escolha um estado</option>
</select>
```

```php
<?php

    $idestado = $_GET['estado'];

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_selectdb('proxima-corrida');

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM proxc_cidade WHERE estado_cidade = ".$idestado);

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
        echo "<option value='".$row['id_cidade']."'>".$row['cidade']."</option>";

   }

?>
```

Comment: Podes colocar `console.log('log: ', this.value);` na primeira linha dentro de `$('#estados').change(function(){` e verificar se isso é chamado quando mudas de estado de novo?

Comment: Cuidado com [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). Pois se eu utilizar o firebug ou ferramenta parecida para colocar um elemento `<option value="5; DELETE FROM proxc_cidade; --">pwned</option>` na combobox e selecioná-lo, sua aplicação já era.

Comment: ok!! estou ainda em homologação.. não vou deixar assim o injeção de SQL @Victor Stafusa

Comment: e sobre o console.log @Sergio está retornando UNDEFINED

Comment: @AnaPaulaMoraes 2 perguntas: 1- o console aparece cada vez que o select muda? 2- no HTML o value dessas option está certo ou o value é `undefined`?

Comment: então @Sergio, 1- no console aparece sim cada vez que muda. 2- e no HTML aparece o sim o VALUE da option, não está aparecendo mais undefined.

Assim, o AJAX chega a carregar os estados e cidades certo.

Um exemplo, se eu seleciono PARANA ele carrega as CIDADES;
Quando eu vou selecionar um segundo ESTADO ele já para de carregar as CIDADES daquele segundo ESTADO selecionado.

Estou achando que seja algum conflito com o framework Jquery Mobile

Comment: @AnaPaulaMoraes podes colocar na pergunta um link para o pastebin com o HTML renderizado da página?

Comment: @Sergio desculpe, não entendi. Posso enviar o link pelo comentário?!

Comment: @AnaPaulaMoraes sim pode ser.

Comment: @sergio segue http://www.domadigital.com/proxima-corrida/
acho viável você acessar do celular.

Comment: @AnaPaulaMoraes estás a carregar o jQuery 1.10 e em seguida o 1.3. Podes tirar a versão 1.3, só vai causar problemas...

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99107/listar-estados-cidades-e-bairros-em-formul%C3%A1rio-de-cadastro/99133#99133

Answer (score 4):

Fiz um exemplo para não depender da programação, apenas javascript. O arquivo com as cidades e estados estão em https://api.myjson.com/bins/enzld. Será feita uma consulta neste arquivo e depois populado os demais campos. O arquivo em javascript acredito que esteja bem simples, qualquer dúvida pergunte que posso lhe explicar os itens que não entender.

No seu caso, você pode gerar essa listagem como JSON via PHP ou até mesmo consumir um arquivo estático como este do exemplo.

```js
var estados = [];

function loadEstados(element) {
  if (estados.length > 0) {
    putEstados(element);
    $(element).removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/enzld',
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(element).html('<option>Carregando...</option>');
      }
    }).done(function(response) {
      estados = response.estados;
      putEstados(element);
      $(element).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
  }
}

function putEstados(element) {

  var label = $(element).data('label');
  label = label ? label : 'Estado';

  var options = '<option value="">' + label + '</option>';
  for (var i in estados) {
    var estado = estados[i];
    options += '<option value="' + estado.sigla + '">' + estado.nome + '</option>';
  }

  $(element).html(options);
}

function loadCidades(element, estado_sigla) {
  if (estados.length > 0) {
    putCidades(element, estado_sigla);
    $(element).removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: theme_url + '/assets/json/estados.json',
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(element).html('<option>Carregando...</option>');
      }
    }).done(function(response) {
      estados = response.estados;
      putCidades(element, estado_sigla);
      $(element).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
  }
}

function putCidades(element, estado_sigla) {
  var label = $(element).data('label');
  label = label ? label : 'Cidade';

  var options = '<option value="">' + label + '</option>';
  for (var i in estados) {
    var estado = estados[i];
    if (estado.sigla != estado_sigla)
      continue;
    for (var j in estado.cidades) {
      var cidade = estado.cidades[j];
      options += '<option value="' + cidade + '">' + cidade + '</option>';
    }
  }
  $(element).html(options);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  loadEstados('#uf');
  $(document).on('change', '#uf', function(e) {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    if (target) {
      loadCidades(target, $(this).val());
    }
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="uf" class="input-label">Estado</label>
  <select name="uf" id="uf" disabled data-target="#cidade">
        <option value="">Estado</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="cidade" class="input-label">Cidade</label>
  <select name="cidade" id="cidade" disabled>
        <option value="">Cidade</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fantásico, muito bom, obrigado pelo excelente código.

Comment: Obrigado @adventistapr, ;) Esse é um exemplo de código com javascript puro, aconselho a apenas usar este exemplo para aprender e depois, utilize um framework tipo Vuejs que não consumiria 80% do que foi digitado ali. rsrsr

Answer (score 0):

Para que o ajax do jQuery seja carregado todas as vezes, você pode usar o método delegate do JQuery, exemplo:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).delegate('#estados', 'change', function() {
    var valor = $('#estados').val();
    $('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado=' + valor );
   });
 });
```