# Listar estados, cidades e bairros em formulário de cadastro

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma tabela chamada "anuncio", onde preciso cadastrar as informações vindas de outras 03 tabelas, são elas:

Tabelas de Estados, Cidades e Bairros.

O objetivo é de que o proprio usuario faça o cadastramento dos imóveis via formulário, adcionando as informações sobre o imóvel, assim montando seu anuncio.

Já tentei trazer as informações via Select de cada Tabela, mas não obtive sucesso, e não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso.

Pensei em usar o ComboBox mas não consegui tambem.

Estou anexando as imagens das tabelas para os amigos darem uma analisada, e quem sabe me orientar de como fazer com que eu consiga gravar as informações na tabela anuncio, via formulário php e Sql.

As informações que constam na tabela "anuncio", foram inseridas diretamente no BD.

Anexo tambem o endereço para ser analisado, pois o sistema de busca com o combobox esta funcionando mediante a cadastro direto no Banco de Dados.

Endereço de acesso para teste: http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/

Tabela Anuncio:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Estados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Cidades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Bairros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se os amigos puderem me dar essa ajuda e me mostrarem como devo fazer para cadastrar de forma que fique como esta na tabela "anuncio", ou seja as informações se cruzam para obter sucesso na busca.

Grande abraço à todos, e meus agradecimentos pela atenção.

Comment: Você não consegue montar o código php ou as queries? A meu ver select e combo box são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Você não sabe como montar a página, não sabe como víncular os dados, como pegar os dados da página ou não sabe nada? Sua pergunta foi extremamente vaga sobre o que você deseja.

Answer (score 9):

## Normalização

Primeiramente recomendo normalizar sua tabela de anúncios, se já possui tabelas para armazenar estados, cidades e bairros, você só precisa de ter o código de bairro na tabela anúncios, pois com esse código você irá conseguir recuperar as outras informações. Ficaria assim:

**Tabela Anúncios**

```
id               int(11)     unsigned     not null     auto increment
cod_bairro       int(11)     unsigned     not null
foto             varchar(250)
```

Observe que agora sua tabela só possui o código do bairro que é obrigatório, porem recuperando o registro do bairro, é possível recuperar a cidade, e ai poderá recuperar o estado.

Em alguns casos é interessante fazer igual você fez, porem é preferível usar uma camada de cache desnormalizada, mas isso é outro assunto.

**Tabela Bairro**

```
id               int(11)     unsigned     not null     auto increment
cod_cidade       int(11)     unsigned     not null
nome             varchar(250)
```

**Tabela Cidade**

```
id               int(11)     unsigned     not null     auto increment
cod_estado       int(11)     unsigned     not null
nome             varchar(250)
```

**Tabela Estado**

```
id               int(11)     unsigned     not null     auto increment
nome             varchar(250)
uf               char(2)
```

## Montando o formulário

Seu formulário deverá ter 3 campos `select` e um para anexo da foto. Para montar  você precisará buscar no seu banco de dados apenas a lista de estados, porem terá que criar outras duas funções ou arquivos para listar as cidades e bairros de acordo com o que o usuário selecionar.

Por exemplo, o usuário ao preencher o formulário seleciona um estado, daí é feita uma chamada Ajax para obter as cidades passando o código do estado selecionado. E o mesmo acontece ao selecionar a cidade e obter a lista de bairros.

No código abaixo foi usado PDO para consultas no banco e o jQuery para o Javascript.

**Buscando estado**

```
$sqlEstado = 'SELECT * FROM estado ORDER BY nome ASC';
$resEstado = $conexao->prepare($sqlEstado);
$resEstado->execute();
$estados = $resEstado->fetchAll();
```

**Formulário**

```
<form action="salvar_anuncio.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
    <select name="estado" id="estado" required>
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <?php foreach ($estados as $estado) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $estado['id'] ?>"><?php echo $estado['nome'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
    <select name="cidade" id="cidade" disabled required>
        <option value="">Selecione um estado</option>
    </select>

    <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label>
    <select name="bairro" id="bairro" disabled required>
        <option value="">Selecione uma cidade</option>
    </select>

    <label for="foto">Foto:</label>
    <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">

    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript para o formulário**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#estado').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'lista_cidades.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {'estado': $('#estado').val()},
            // Antes de carregar os registros, mostra para o usuário que está
            // sendo carregado.
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $('#cidade').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#cidade').html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');

                $('#bairro').html('<option value="">Selecione uma cidade</option>');
                $('#bairro').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            // Após carregar, coloca a lista dentro do select de cidades.
            success: function(data) {
                if ($('#estado').val() !== '') {
                    // Adiciona o retorno no campo, habilita e da foco
                    $('#cidade').html('<option value="">Selecione</option>');
                    $('#cidade').append(data);
                    $('#cidade').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
                } else {
                    $('#cidade').html('<option value="">Selecione um estado</option>');
                    $('#cidade').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                    $('#bairro').html('<option value="">Selecione uma cidade</option>');
                    $('#bairro').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('#cidade').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'lista_bairros.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {'cidade': $('#cidade').val()},
            // Antes de carregar os registros, mostra para o usuário que está
            // sendo carregado.
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $('#bairro').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#bairro').html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');
            },
            // Após carregar, coloca a lista dentro do select de bairros.
            success: function(data) {
                if ($('#cidade').val() !== '') {
                    // Adiciona o retorno no campo, habilita e da foco
                    $('#bairro').html('<option value="">Selecione</option>');
                    $('#bairro').append(data);
                    $('#bairro').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
                } else {
                    $('#bairro').html('<option value="">Selecione uma cidade</option>');
                    $('#bairro').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Arquivo lista_cidades.php**

```
<?php
// Uma forma de obter $_POST['estado'] mais segura
$codEstado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estado', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

$sqlCidade = 'SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE cod_estado = :codestado ORDER BY nome ASC';
$resCidade = $conexao->prepare($sqlCidade);
$resCidade->execute(array(
    ':codestado' => $codEstado
));
$cidades = $resCidade->fetchAll();
?>

<?php foreach ($cidades as $cidade) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cidade['id'] ?>"><?php echo $cidade['nome'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

**Arquivo lista_bairros.php**

```
<?php
// Uma forma de obter $_POST['cidade'] mais segura
$codCidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

$sqlBairro = 'SELECT * FROM bairro WHERE cod_cidade = :codcidade ORDER BY nome ASC';
$resBairro = $conexao->prepare($sqlBairro);
$resBairro->execute(array(
    ':codcidade' => $codCidade
));
$bairros = $resBairro->fetchAll();
?>

<?php foreach ($bairros as $bairro) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $bairro['id'] ?>"><?php echo $bairro['nome'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

**SQL para buscar Anúncios**\

```
SELECT
    a.`id`,
    a.`foto`,
    e.`nome`,
    e.`uf`,
    c.`nome`,
    b.`nome`
FROM `anuncio` AS a
INNER JOIN `bairro` AS b
ON a.`cod_bairro` = b.`id`
INNER JOIN `cidade` AS c
ON b.`cod_cidade` = c.`id`
INNER JOIN `estado` AS e
ON c.`cod_estado` = e.`id`
WHERE
    -- Condicoes
```

Comment: Olá marcusagm, Gostaria de agradecer a sua dica, pois com ela me abriu a mente e consegui fazer o que desejava. Pois a sua dica de cadastrar somente os códigos dos estado, cidades e bairros solucionou o meu problema . Assim que terminar e confirma a funcionalidade postarei como ficou o código junto com o form, valeu?
Mais uma vez muito obrigado pela sua ajuda,

Comment: Boa tarde marcusagm, estou testando seu código, mas no formulário seleciono qualquer estado e não faz nada, pode me dar uma idéia?

Comment: Bom pode ser várias coisas, adicionou o jquery? O id referenciado no JavaScript está com o mesmo nome? Ex `input id="estado` e `$('#estafo')` caso não seja nada disso, abre o Firebug e vê se em console não está acusando ninguém erro

Comment: Peguei o código exatamente como está aqui, fiz um include da conexão em todos arquivos, adicionei o jquery logo abaixo do </head>....estou revisando tudo mas não acho o motivo do problema. No console do chrome não encontrei nada, vou tentar o firebug

Comment: Vc pode mudar de `$('estado').on('change', ...` para de `$('estado').change(function () {...`

Comment: Se for isso é versão do jquery o problema

Comment: coloquei o jquery 1.8.2 e deu certo, habilita a cidade mas não acha nenhum cidade, fica circulado em vermelho. O que isso significa? Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Tem cidade cadastrada pro estado selecionado? Se a borda ficou vermelha pode ser pq o caso do campo com foco está definido com borda vermelha ou pq tem formatação para campo requerido quando enviar o formulário. Por algum motivo teve uma tentativa de enviar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32322/discussion-between-diego-and-marcusagm).

Comment: Ah, mais um detalhezinho que esqueci, se por exemplo vou até o bairro e recomeço o estado, o bairro fica com as seleções antigas. Tem como bloquear/mudar isso?

Comment: tem sim vou atualizar a resposta e te mando no chat

Comment: Cara, se eu precisasse passar de novo o campo "estado" para o ultimo combo, como faria? tentei inserir data: {'estado': $('#estado').val()}, embaixo do data: {'cidade': $('#cidade').val()}, mas nao deu. Obrigado!

Comment: `data: {'cidade': $('#cidade').val(), 'estado': $('estado').val()}`

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Deu certo, tive que tratar o $resBairro->execute(array(
    ':codcidade' => $codCidade
)); e ai funcionou.

Comment: E se eu quisesse setar o retorno em um input, não em um combo? o lista_cidade retorna valor, mas não consigo setar. Tem uma idéia? Fiz dessa forma: <?php foreach ($retornos as $retorno) { ?>
    <input type "text" value="<?php echo $retorno['usuario'] ?>"><?php echo $retorno['usuario'] ?>
<?php }

Comment: Não tem sentido isso. O input text permite apenas digitar um texto qualquer e não selecionar uma opção. Se vc quer que a pessoa possa digitar e aparecer as opções abaixo use algum plugin de autocomplete.

Comment: Na verdade eu seleciono um valor e o retorno seria colocado nesse input. É como se fosse um formulário de alteração sabe? Se eu coloco um combo o valor aparece, mas se mudo para um campo de input o valor não aparece...

Comment: Se quiser exibir todos os campos text vai ter que substituir o select para uma div