# Selecionar e exibir dados com Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte `ajax`:

```
var id = $('#idCliente').val();
$.ajax( 
{ 
    url:"/Administrar/chamadas/ajax/endereco/" + id, 
    dataType : 'json', 
    success:function(result) { 
        $('[name^="cham_endereco[]"]').val(result.endereco); 
        $('[name^="cham_numero[]"]').val(result.numero); 
        $('[name^="cham_cidade"]').val(result.cidade); 
        $('[name^="cham_bairro"]').val(result.bairro); 
    } 
});
```

Neste caso eu recupero os dados de endereço do cliente, para preencher automaticamente os campos, o retorno é desta forma:

> {"endereco":"R
>   MANDAGUARI","bairro":"25","cidade":"1","estado":16,"cep":83324410,"numero":"1316","capital":true}

Até o retorno, tudo certo. Porém, no sistema eu uso um select para selecionar primeiro a cidade e ai sim o bairro... Neste caso, seleciona a cidade automaticamente, porém, o bairro não é selecionado (porque não está carregado por um ajax).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso chamar o bairro no ajax, para que carregue automaticamente na tela e selecione o bairro que está sendo requisitado?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc tem o bairro no retorno do Ajax mas ele não carrega no html, isso?

Comment: Exatamente, eu tenho esse retorno do bairro... Mas preciso elaborar algum jquery que carregue estes bairros... pelo seguinte, no campo de baixo, quando seleciona a cidade, já vem o bairro.. (funciona) mas no caso da cidade já selecionada, não dá o onchange para carregar os bairros... entendeu? :)

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse código, usei ele aqui. Não é dificil adaptar ao seu: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99107/listar-estados-cidades-e-bairros-em-formulário-de-cadastro/99133#99133

Answer (score 3):

Você pode chamar o ajax quando altera o campo cidade, se você já trouxer o campo cidade preenchido pode chamar o ajax quando terminar de carregar a pagina.

Para chamar quando altera faz dessa forma...

```
$(function() {
  $('cidade').change(function(e) {
    //chama o ajax aqui
  }); 
});
```

Se o campo ja vier preenchido pode fazer assim...

```
$(function() {
  if ($('cidade').val() > 0) {
    //chama o ajax aqui
    //popule o campo estado
  } 
});
```

Para popular o campo select com as opções pegue o resultado do retorno do ajax e faça dessa forma...

```
$('bairro').append('<option value="0">Nome do Bairro</option>');
```

No seu caso ficaria assim

```
<select id='cliente'>
  <option>Selecione o cliente</option>
  <option>Cliente 1</option>
  <option>Cliente 2</option>
</select>

<select  id='cidade'>
</select>

<select  id='bairro'>
</select>
```

E seu script assim...

```
$(function(){
  $('#cliente').change(function(e) {
      $('#cidade').append('<option value="1">Cidade 1</option>');
      $('#cidade').append('<option value="2">Cidade 2</option>');
      $('#cidade').val(2);
      $('#cidade').change();
    }); 
  $('#cidade').change(function(e) {
    //chama o ajax que busca os bairros aqui
    $('#bairro').append('<option value="1">Bairro 1</option>');
    $('#bairro').append('<option value="2">Bairro 2</option>');
    $('#bairro').val(2);
  }); 
});
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/4zqzh0c1/2/)

Comment: Entendi um pouco, não entendo muito de ajax... Como eu faria a adaptação no código citado?

Comment: Em que momento você faz esse ajax que citou? Quando carrega a página? Você precisa ter outro ajax que busca os bairros, da mesma forma que você fez o do endereço. Porem no retorno deve ser diferente.
Depois disso paga o id do bairro e seta para selecionar o bairro do endereço. Montei um exemplo.... https://jsfiddle.net/4zqzh0c1/

Comment: Este ajax que eu citei, é quando eu seleciono o cliente (<select>), ai ele busca os dados do endereço e preenche os primeiros campos que estão apresentados na imagem

Comment: Andre, da uma olhada que editei a resposta, coloquei um exemplo funcionando pra ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

Dispare o evento 'change' na caixa de seleção da cidade após selecionar seu valor:

```
$('cidade').trigger('change');
```

Então após a busca dos bairros selecione o que vem do seu Ajax.