# recuperar dados em um list para edição

Tags: php, mysql, crud, html-select

Em uma pagina de edição dos dados de cadastro, como preencher um selec com a informação salva originalmente.

Ex. No formulario de cadastro, foi selecionado num select, uma cidade. Despois de salvo, ha opção de editar os dados, porem não estou conseguindo exibir no select a cidade original, e listar as demais, para opção de alteração.

Estou tentando com php esta operação, porem não estou conseguindo. Como posso estar fazendo?

Comment: Veja esse tópico: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99107/listar-estados-cidades-e-bairros-em-formul%c3%a1rio-de-cadastro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que a forma mais fácil é a seguinte:

Salve todas as cidades/estados em uma tabela separada no banco de dados. Vamos supor que essa tabela é formada pelas colunas:

**id | Cidade | UF**

Então eu faria o seguinte:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cidades ORDER BY cidade ASC");

echo '<select name="cidade">';
while($exe = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$selected = ($exe['id'] == $id_salva_da_cidade_na_outra_tabela) ? 'selected' : '';

echo '<option value="'.$exe['id'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$exe['cidade'].' - '.$exe['uf'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Se você tiver as cidades salvas em um `array` e não em banco de dados:

```
<?php
$array = array('sp'=>'São Paulo', 'sp'=>'Osasco', 'rj'=>'Rio de Janeiro');

echo '<select name="cidade">';
foreach($array as $uf=>$cidade){

$selected = ($uf == $uf_salva_no_banco_de_dados) ? 'selected' : '';

echo '<option value="'.$uf.'" '.$selected.'>'.$cidade.' - '.$uf.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Eu usso essas saídas quando tenho que auto-preencher um `select` para editar dados.

Comment: Perfeito Alisson, funcionou certinho. o que estava faltando era a parte do $select... Agora esta funcionando perfeitamente. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.